# Integrate Devexpress tool in Asp.net Core Application on the VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, devexpress, asp.net-core-2.0, devexpress-mvc

I am trying to refer to the `Devexpress tool in ASP.net Core application in the VS Code.`

I am not able to refer to the `DevExpress tool in VS code` which is in not show the reference option. can you help me how will reference the dll in VS code I tried but no luck..

```
Is it possible to integrate Devexpress tool in VS Code?.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution, review the Using [.NET Core in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet) article that describes a general approach how to create a new .NET Core application in Visual Studio Code. Then refer to this [article](https://js.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Guide/ASP.NET_MVC_Controls/Prerequisites_and_Installation/#Add_or_Upgrade_the_Resources_in_an_Existing_Project/Manually_in_ASPNET_Core_MVC) to learn how to add the `DevExpress ASP.NET Controls` to the project.
While it is possible to use this component in VS Code as well, we don't recommend you do so. The Bootstrap for ASP.NET Core product line is in maintenance mode and not developed anymore. Use the ASP.NET Core DataGrid and other ASP.NET Core controls instead.

Answer (score 2):

I used their controls for many years and know that they fully support Visual Studio. So I guess they should work in VS Codde as well, but I do not use VS Code so I cannot be sure. I suggest you to [contact their support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) or look in their [support database](https://search.devexpress.com/?q=How%20to%20use%20%20ASP.NEt%20Core%20in%20VS%20Code&f=0&m=SupportCenter).